# Is there anyway to automatically mount a filesystem when I open a symbolic link to a directory on that filesystem?

Tags: arch-linux, filesystems, mount, symlink, automounting

I am using Arch with Xfce.

Recently, I have created a symbolic link to a directory on a filesystem.

But I don't want to mount the filesystem during boot or manually mount it before I open the symbolic link.

Is there anyway to auto-mount that filesystem when I open the symbolic link to the directory on that filesystem?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do this with `systemd`, so you don't have to install extra software and just have a small amount of extra configuration.

Simply add `noauto,x-systemd.automount` to the options in `fstab`.

`noauto` to not mount automatically on boot and `x-systemd.automount` to let systemd mount it on access.

After adding x-systemd.automount to an `fstab` line, you need to run:

```
  sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

And then one, or both, of the following:

```
  sudo systemctl restart remote-fs.target
  sudo systemctl restart local-fs.target
```

Then the automount will become active and usable.

Source: [ArchWiki - fstab](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Fstab#Automount_with_systemd)

Answer (score 22):

[`autofs`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Autofs) can do this for you. You can configure any number of mountpoints with various options, and the corresponding filesystems are mounted whenever the mountpoint is accessed. After a given amount of inactivity the filesystems are unmounted again.

There are no doubt various ways of using `autofs`, but here's one way of doing what you're trying to do, based on the way I used to use it.

You start with a directory which will hold a number of `autofs` mount-points (well, at least one); say `/misc`. You don't need to create it, but you do need to create a configuration file which will describe all the filesystems you want to mount there; for example, I could mount CDs, DVDs and Blu-Rays with the following file, saved as `/etc/auto.misc`:

```
cd              -fstype=iso9660,ro,nosuid,nodev    :/dev/cdrom
br              -fstype=udf,ro,nosuid,nodev        :/dev/cdrom
```

The general syntax is the mountpoint, followed by any options introduced by `-`, then the mountpoint introduced by `:` on a local system. (I'm simplifying here, see the [`autofs(5)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/autofs.5.html) manpage for details.)

Then this file is enabled by adding an entry in `/etc/auto.master`:

```
/misc   /etc/auto.misc
```

Restart `autofs` with

```
sudo service autofs restart
```

and you should be able to run

```
ls /misc/cd
```

and see the contents of any CD in your drive. (Obviously replace the name and mount target by whatever is appropriate in your case.)

Once you have that, you can link to anything in the auto-mounted filesystems from anywhere else, in the same way as if they were standard, non-auto-mounted filesystems. So in my example,

```
ln -s /misc/br blu-ray
```

creates a `blu-ray` link wherever the command is run. You can link further into the filesystem as well,

```
ln -s /misc/br/BDMV autolinktest
```

creates an `autolinktest` link to the movie contents. Accessing the links will mount the target filesystem.