# Mount numerous SquashFS images

Tags: linux, mount, performance, nginx, squashfs

I am trying to configure a web server so that it can serve web apps using NGINX. We expect to have 15,000 different web apps. Each web app is supposed to be packaged in a SquashFS image, containing a lot of assets (up to 1.5 Gb).

I made a first try to mount 15,000 SquashFS images sequentially in a script, and it takes forever: 40 minutes, during which time the system's performance collapses. I am talking about the mounting, not the actual file serving.

Is there a way to improve this performance? What other file system could I use? In particular, I would be strongly interested in a file system that could be "lazily" mounted, only when NGINX tries to read from the mount point directory.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there anyway to automatically mount a filesystem when I open a symbolic link to a directory on that filesystem?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/196397/is-there-anyway-to-automatically-mount-a-filesystem-when-i-open-a-symbolic-link)